# Use AlarmManager without a service

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

Is it possible to use AlarmManager to run an alarm without the app using a service. AlarmManager would have to bring the device out of sleep mode and execute my code in onReceive. Virtually every code sample I have seen posted here shows a service being used. Yet the Android docs do not mention the need of having a service.

Comment: Put your link in a solution and I'll check it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an working example,

activity_alarm_manager.xml file's code

```
<linearlayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

   <button android:id="@+id/btStart" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" android:onclick="startRepeatingTimer"
     android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium" android:text="@string/btStart"  
     tools:context=".WidgetAlarmManagerActivity"/>
   <button android:id="@+id/btCancel" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" android:onclick="cancelRepeatingTimer" 
     android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium" android:text="@string/btCancel"
     tools:context=".WidgetAlarmManagerActivity"/>
    <button android:id="@+id/btOneTime" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:onclick="onetimeTimer"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium" android:text="@string/btOneTime"  
    tools:context=".WidgetAlarmManagerActivity"/>
  </linearlayout>
```

BroadcastReceiver's code,

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
         //Acquire the lock
         wl.acquire();

         //You can do the processing here.
         Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
         StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();

         if(extras != null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)){
          //Make sure this intent has been sent by the one-time timer button.
          msgStr.append("One time Timer : ");
         }
         Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
         msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));

         Toast.makeText(context, msgStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         //Release the lock
         wl.release();
 }

 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        //After after 5 seconds
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 5 , pi);
    }

    public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }

    public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context){
     AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.TRUE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml's code

```
<manifest android:versioncode="1" android:versionname="1.0"
       package="com.rakesh.alarmmanagerexample"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <uses-sdk android:minsdkversion="10" android:targetsdkversion="15"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm_manager"
           android:name="com.rakesh.alarmmanagerexample.AlarmManagerActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.rakesh.alarmmanagerexample.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver">
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

AlarmManagerActivity.java file's code

```
public class AlarmManagerActivity extends Activity {

 private AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver alarm;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_manager);
        alarm = new AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    @Override
 protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
 }

    public void startRepeatingTimer(View view) {
     Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
     if(alarm != null){
      alarm.SetAlarm(context);
     }else{
      Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    }

    public void cancelRepeatingTimer(View view){
     Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
     if(alarm != null){
      alarm.CancelAlarm(context);
     }else{
      Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    }

    public void onetimeTimer(View view){
     Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
     if(alarm != null){
      alarm.setOnetimeTimer(context);
     }else{
      Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_widget_alarm_manager, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

A Reference Link from [Github](https://github.com/rakeshcusat/Code4Reference/tree/master/AndroidProjects/AlarmManagerExample)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Give `AlarmManager` a `PendingIntent` with Intent filter of a particular `BroadCastReciever`.
2. Declare this receiver in the app's manifest along with the intent
   filter.
3. That receiver's `onRecieve()` will get called by `AlarmManager`.

No Services involved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it matters I set a periodic event from an `Activity` by passing it is a `Context` and it does not seem to matter which context is passed.

The passed `context` is only used in getting the `PendingIntent` from `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`and from looking at the [source of 4.2.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/app/PendingIntent.java#PendingIntent.getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,int,android.content.Intent,int%29) :

```
/**
 * Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast, like calling
 * {@link Context#sendBroadcast(Intent) Context.sendBroadcast()}.
 *
 * @param context The Context in which this PendingIntent should perform
 * the broadcast.
 * @param requestCode Private request code for the sender (currently
 * not used).
 * @param intent The Intent to be broadcast.
 * @param flags May be {@link #FLAG_ONE_SHOT}, {@link #FLAG_NO_CREATE},
 * {@link #FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT}, {@link #FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT},
 * or any of the flags as supported by
 * {@link Intent#fillIn Intent.fillIn()} to control which unspecified parts
 * of the intent that can be supplied when the actual send happens.
 *
 * @return Returns an existing or new PendingIntent matching the given
 * parameters.  May return null only if {@link #FLAG_NO_CREATE} has been
 * supplied.
 */
public static PendingIntent getBroadcast(Context context, int requestCode,
        Intent intent, int flags) {
    return getBroadcastAsUser(context, requestCode, intent, flags,
            new UserHandle(UserHandle.myUserId()));
}

/**
 * @hide
 * Note that UserHandle.CURRENT will be interpreted at the time the
 * broadcast is sent, not when the pending intent is created.
 */
public static PendingIntent getBroadcastAsUser(Context context, int requestCode,
        Intent intent, int flags, UserHandle userHandle) {
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    String resolvedType = intent != null ? intent.resolveTypeIfNeeded(
            context.getContentResolver()) : null;
    try {
        intent.setAllowFds(false);
        IIntentSender target =
            ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().getIntentSender(
                ActivityManager.INTENT_SENDER_BROADCAST, packageName,
                null, null, requestCode, new Intent[] { intent },
                resolvedType != null ? new String[] { resolvedType } : null,
                flags, null, userHandle.getIdentifier());
        return target != null ? new PendingIntent(target) : null;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can see that the passed `context` is only used to get the package name and the resolved type and isn't stored in the `PendingIntent` or anything which might cause some problems and leaks.

Comment: That does not appear to be true. I used an action in the Pending intent instead of using a context and then the onReceive got fired. Using a context worked initially in my app but eventually failed to get triggered. Using an action guarantees that the AlarmManager will create an instance of your class. Context are not all the same and there are plenty of people who have had problems getting onReceive to get fired.

Comment: @AndroidDev How did you get a broadcast `PendingIntent` with out passing a `context`? Did you not use this function : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)

Comment: I was referring to the Intent and not the context parameter of getBroadcast. You don't need a context for the Intent. I use an action message instead.